# Use CakePHP scaffolding in production mode

Tags: cakephp

In order to avoid this to be a 'personal question', I would like to know if there are any technical disadvantages to using the `$scaffold` var when you're in production 'mode'.

The documentation says that it's not advised because it's not flexible enough. However it still works, also when debug level is 0.

I have some models/tables that are quite simple and will do perfectly with the default scaffolding options.. so are there any real reasons to not use scaffolding in production?

Comment: As you said it's not flexible at all. When you need to change somenthing you'll need to create the view. BTW, create the view with cake bake is fast and easy. Actually I don't know if it's better have the view or use scaffolding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the application. If you do not care that every user has CRUD access, then feel free. Especially if it is an internal app where you have more control over users versus an open public app.

Then if you need to start making alterations, you can simply BAKE the code and start modifying. Easy peasy.

Comment: Oh I see.. I had forgotten to bake the Controllers with CRUD methods.. so all my attempts failed and thus I thought I had to keep using $scaffold